# Setting CommandTimeout to solve lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an error like this

> lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction

Maybe I didn't understand it. But I've a solution if I set CommandTimeout=1000 or something higher. I didn't try it in production yet. But I'd like to hear any opinion on this.

```
// 40 lines of command.Parameters here
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("sample1", sam1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("sample2", sam2);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("sample3", sam2);
try
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (MySqlException mex)
{
```

Comment: lock means that a row/column/table is locked - and that can be caused by another insert/update statement

Comment: @fubo, so how do I fix this.?

Comment: if this error appears every time, you should search for "deadlock" - but it's not possible to answer this without knowing the statement

Comment: I too am having this issue...however increasing my CommandTimeout did not solve the issue. The CommandTimeout is different than the lock wait timeout. The "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" setting in my.ini governs what that timeout is, and the default is 50 seconds. From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving "lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction" intermittently. Then I started wrapping everything in transactions and I stopped receiving those errors. This should prevent table locks from remaining after the query is executed.

(Assuming "conn" is a MySqlConnection, "iLevel" is the isolation level you want to use, and "query" contains your query as a string)

```
int rowCount = 0; // In case you want the number of rows affected

try
{
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);   

    using(var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(iLevel))
    {   
        command.Transaction = transaction;                 
        command.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;

        // Set parameters etc...

        try
        {
            rowCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();         
            // Handle query exception...            
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Handle general exception...
}
```

Comment: Also I should mention I passed in "iLevel" to the BeginTransaction function. This is a variable that holds the isolation level you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could try (just for testing purposes) set transaction isolation level = 
"READ COMMITTED" and if this fails try set to  "READ UNCOMMITTED"
[MySql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html)
check for dead lock:

> "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" from the MySQL Command line client (not a
>   query browser) will give you info on deadlocks.
>
> Deadlocks can also be caused by uncommitted transactions (usually
>   program bugs) and the person who is running the uncommitted
>   transaction will not see the problem as they will be working fine
>   (through their data will not be committed).  [Quote from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643122/how-to-detect-deadlocks-in-mysql-innodb)